# How to autocomplete the user's first name in an HTML input box?

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple bootstrap form.
In this form, in the first input box, I ask for name. I want to enable autocomplete. The user shall be able to select the first name, like a form where if you click you have all data the user usually enters in similar forms.
How can I achieve that?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-required="true">
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Also, I'm struggling a bit with your English. Are you trying to add a dropdown with a list of name options?

Comment: @pette  ,  I have modified the title and the contents of your question. Please check if it still reflects what you want to achieve.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl is good! thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an attribute called autocomplete on HTML tags that are related to forms. For the first name you could specify `autocomplete="given-name"` and for the last name you could use `autocomplete="family-name"`.

There is more information at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Comment: what difference will it make? I don't think it will have any effect then why we use it why not use "on" instead