# how cache detect forms inputs like firstname and lastname and distribute value in them

Tags: javascript, forms, input, autocomplete, browser-cache

when we hover on form in any website the dialog box is displayed and when we click on that dailog box. input fields are detected like first name or last name or may be address .My question is that how browser detects the exect input field and distribute values in them .like using name , id type of input field or other process are used .if possible give some references too.thanks
js developers..web

how cache detect form fields and distribute inputs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you talking about the 'autocomplete' html attribute? Like when you are signin up on a web site and the Email field is pre-filled?

Comment: yes. not only email but first and last name pre filled if we hover on form

Comment: You can look at [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) or to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70743718/how-to-autocomplete-the-users-first-name-in-an-html-input-box

Comment: Basically, you have to set the `autocomplete` html attribute on the input with the value that refers to the field you need, for example `autocomplete="username"` will tell the browser that that input/field can be prefilled by the browser with a username or an email

Comment: basically, I want to know the backend process that how the browser detects the input fields to distribute the field's value. i-e when we hover over the field how browser fills the first name value exactly and the same others fields. why the last name is not filled into the first name input field?

Comment: Have you take a look into the docs? Usually, it's not the backend to cache the inputs values.
From the MDN Web Docs: "The source of the suggested values is generally up to the browser; typically values come from past values entered by the user, but they may also come from pre-configured values. For instance, a browser might let the user save their name, address, phone number, and email addresses for autocomplete purposes. Perhaps the browser offers the ability to save encrypted credit card information, for autocompletion following an authentication procedure."
Does this answer your question?

Comment: "why the last name is not filled into the first name input field?" With wich value have you set the autocomplete tag? Usually for full name you must set `autocomplete="name"` but it depends also from the values saved in your browser

Comment: I understand and appreciate your effort but I am a js developer and want to know how browser code identifies input fields to fill exactly i-e when we hover over the form browser detects the first name input field and inserts a cache or saved the first name value in that. So I am interested to know why the browser does not fill email into the first name technically.

Comment: The autocomplete html tag are used by the browser to detected with field is it (email, name, lastname etc), the browser cache the values using previous inputed values (on other forms/sites).
That's how it works, no js needed for that, if this doesn't answer to your question, I suggest you to elaborate/clarify the question because that's the response for your current question.

If your looking for the code used by the browser to detected the automplete tags and fill them, you can look into the repositorie of Chronium 
 (https://github.com/chromium/chromium) or of another open source browser